# Point charge moving towards a conducting plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, point-particles

A point charge $q$ of mass $m$ is released from rest at a distance $d$ from an infinite grounded conducting plane. Show that the charge hits the plane after an amount of time given by:

$ \Delta t= \frac{\pi d} {q} \sqrt{2\pi\epsilon_0md} $

I can't seem to start this one. I'm assuming I need to start by finding the force by the charge as a function of $z$, and setting it equal to $\frac{md^2z}{dt} $ giving a differential equation. The diff eq. seems hard to solve, but a hint I recieved was to multiply both sides by $\frac{dz}{dt}$, but I don't see how this simplifies the problem.

Comment: Use [the method of images!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges)

Comment: use the method of images to find the force. then the trick is to write $\frac{d^2 z}{dt^2}$ as $\dot{z} \frac{d \dot{z}}{dz}$.